# Puppeteer: Facing issue with page.goto(url) and taking screenshot

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, puppeteer

The following code executes the unit test that is it loads the page url, and wait there until timeout, but exit out with error `Error: Timeout of 65000ms exceeded` without taking a screenshot.

```
describe('initial test', function () {

let browser
let page

before(async function () {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('base url')
})

it('should go to new page', async function(){
  this.timeout(65000);
    await page.goto('url', {
        timeout : 0,
        waitLoad: false,
    })

    await page.waitForSelector('selector name', {timeout: 1000})
    await page.waitFor(5000)
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'menu.png' })
})
```

Comment: where is your callback `done`?

Comment: where is `asyc` function declaration?

Comment: Like it was mentioned tersely, your `it` needs to be an `async` function: `it('should go to a new page', async function () { ... })`

Comment: oh, that was a typo, my callback function in `it` is an aysnc function. updated the question